# WebDriverException : "Process unexpectedly closed with status 255" - selenium/geckodriver/AWS lambda - Python

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, aws-lambda, geckodriver

I am currently working on a web scraping project on aws lambda (serverless)

techs :

**python3**

**selenium 3.14**

**geckodriver-V0.29**

**firefox 80.0** (en mode headless)

Here is the code I implemented (knowing that I configured the paths for firefox and geckodriver beforehand) :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options as FirefoxOptions
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary

options = FirefoxOptions()
options.add_argument("--headless")
binary = FirefoxBinary("/tmp/bin/firefox/firefox")

webdriver.Firefox(options=options,executable_path="/tmp/bin/geckodriver", firefox_binary=binary)
```

This is the error I get:

```
Message: Process unexpectedly closed with status 255
: WebDriverException
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/src/lambda_function.py", line 8, in lambda_handler
    driver = WebDriverWrapper()
  File "/var/task/src/webdriver_wrapper.py", line 116, in __init__
    self._driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options,executable_path="/tmp/bin/geckodriver", firefox_binary=binary)
  File "/var/task/lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 174, in __init__
    keep_alive=True)
  File "/var/task/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/var/task/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/var/task/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/var/task/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Process unexpectedly closed with status 255
```

I have searched the forums and articles but have not found a solution. Has anyone experienced this kind of problem and if possible how to correct it?

Answer (score 16):

I've had the same problem these days, apparently it's due to the firefox executables being downloaded directly from the link inside a docker container, which doesn't have a set of libraries firefox needs to work. To solve the problem I therefore had to add the following line to the **Dockerfile**.

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y wget bzip2 libxtst6 libgtk-3-0 libx11-xcb-dev libdbus-glib-1-2 libxt6 libpci-dev && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

To test which libraries were missing, I connected to the docker container and try to run firefox in the following way:

```
firefox -headless
```

Comment: Thank you, that was really helpful to me! :) One suggestion though: It should be sufficient to use `libgtk-3-0` instead of `packagekit-gtk3-module`, as the latter will pull in in whole lot of additional dependencies.

Comment: It works, but indeed only when adding these to the Dockerfile. I'm still unsure why it does not work when executing this in the container. I also removed the last bit `rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*` as this does not seem necessary to achieve the result.

Answer (score 3):

(late answer, left for the next poor soul trying to solve the problem)

You are running headless. Is this running in a VM or Container with no head? Did you install FF from tar?

For me this turned out to be that the instance I was running did not have a desktop installed, and therefore was missing some libraries Firefox depends on. I had installed Firefox from download and unpacked.

To prove this was the problem, I installed Firefox from repo, and then ran my unpacked instance. Seeing that work demonstrated that I was simply missing dependancy libraries.

I have still not figured out the minimal set of libraries to install from Repo.

EDIT: I have found `gitpod`'s `gecko` container to be informative.

https://github.com/gitpod-io/workspace-images/blob/master/gecko/Dockerfile

Answer (score 2):

It's an issue about Firefox.
Try updating Firefox to the latest version.
I think Firefox 80.0 is incompatible with geckodriver v0.29

Answer (score 0):

If your ubuntu didn't install firefox, try this below:

```
sudo apt install firefox
```

It work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed installing Firefox though `apt` instead of `snap` helped. But Ubuntu does not allow it by default. Following this guide: https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2022/04/how-to-install-firefox-deb-apt-ubuntu-22-04 I was able to install Firefox through apt. ✅

Now I can run selenium + firefox headless mode + ubuntu server without additional configuration.